# optgroup with all option

Tags: jquery, html, select, optgroup

my select option group is like

```
<select multiple class="form-control form-white" data-placeholder="Select Courses">
 <option value="all">All</option>
  <optgroup label="Play School">
    <option value="1">All</option>
    <option value="2">Sec A</option>
    <option value="3">Sec B</option>
 </optgroup>
<optgroup label="Nursery">
    <option value="1">All</option>
    <option value="2">Sec A</option>
    <option value="3">Sec C</option>
</optgroup>

<optgroup label="LKG">
    <option value="1">All</option>
    <option value="2">Sec B</option>
```

when i click the main option All remain class option group should be empty, if i click the nursery option-group 'All',the remain section like(Sec A,Sec B) will be disable.is it possible through jquery?

Comment: I don't understand why you would disable the other options, you are stopping users from changing their mind by disabling options in the same drop down as you are using - this will be a massive usability issue

Comment: Do you really mean to use the same `value` for different options? When you submit the form, how will the server know whether `value=2` means `Play School Sec A` or `LKG Sec B`?

Comment: If user select <option value="all">All</option> which means all classes,so  again why we permit to select particular class like `Nursery` `LKG` ?